# while i subtract two time(shift-time) from text boxes and display the output in a text box,the value is returned as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Time difference</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="calculate" action=""> 
<div> 
    <p><label>Start Hour: <input type="time" name="formShiftStartTime" id="formShiftStartTime"/></label></p>
    <p><label>End Hour: <input type="time" name="formShiftEndTime" id="formShiftEndTime" /></label></p>
   
    <!-- <p><label>duration</label></p><p id="formDuration"><label>Duration: </label></p> -->
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Duration</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="formDuration" >
                <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control " id="formDuration" name="formDuration" > -->
                
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- <p id="formDuration">time:<input type="text" name="formDuration" id="formDuration"/></p> -->
    <!-- <p><input id="calculate_time" type="button" value="Calculate Time" /></p> -->
</div> 
</form>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showTime(hours, minutes) {
    return ((hours < 10) ? '0' : '') + hours +
        ':' +
        ((minutes < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutes;
}
function calculate_time(formShiftStartTime, formShiftEndTime) {
    startTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + formShiftStartTime);
    endTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + formShiftEndTime);
    
    var difference = endTime - startTime;
    difference /= 1000 * 60; // convert to minutes
    var hours = Math.floor(difference / 60);
    var mins = Math.floor(difference % 60);
    document.getElementById('formDuration').innerHTML = showTime(hours, mins);
}
document.getElementById('formShiftEndTime').onchange = function () {
    var start = this.form.elements.formShiftStartTime.value;
    var end = this.form.elements.formShiftEndTime.value;
    // calculate_time(start, end);
    document.getElementById("formDuration").value = calculate_time(start, end);
    // $('#formDuration').val(calculate_time(start, end));
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i am new to js.could anyone please help me with this.I want to find the difference between two time from text box(24 hr format) and display the output in another text box.

if the display the time within a `<p>` tag or a `<label>` tag. It works fine.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Add more code, there seems to be nothing in the code section

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Am really sorry for the inconvenience.I have now attached my code. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know whether it worked for you . Happy Coding :)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Time difference</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="calculate" action=""> 
<div> 
    <p><label>Start Hour: <input type="time" name="formShiftStartTime" id="formShiftStartTime"/></label></p>
    <p><label>End Hour: <input type="time" name="formShiftEndTime" id="formShiftEndTime" /></label></p>
   
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Duration</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control " id="formDuration" name="formDuration" > 
                
            </div>

</div> 
</form>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showTime(hours, minutes) {
    return ((hours < 10) ? '0' : '') + hours +
        ':' +
        ((minutes < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutes;
}
function calculate_time(formShiftStartTime, formShiftEndTime) {
    startTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + formShiftStartTime);
    endTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + formShiftEndTime);
    
    var difference = endTime - startTime;
    difference /= 1000 * 60; // convert to minutes
    var hours = Math.floor(difference / 60);
    var mins = Math.floor(difference % 60);
   document.getElementById('formDuration').value =    showTime(hours, mins);
}

$("#formShiftEndTime").on("change", function(){
  var startHour = $("#formShiftStartTime").val();
  var endHour =  $("#formShiftEndTime").val();
  calculate_time(startHour, endHour);
})


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah. It's working, But It's not working for the night shift timings.The answer is calculated in negative values

Comment: Yes.. I asked to display it in the text field and also for night shifts,it is displaying the wrong value.Anyhow thank you :)

Comment: will check and update it :) happy coding .For my understanding night shifts means 08:00:PM to 06:00:AM it should show 12 hours isn't.

Comment: Yes.But, since i am using 24 hour format,night shift here means 18:00-06:00 should show 12 hours

Answer (score 0):

select the first date field as from and second date field as to.

the calculation is done based on to - from.

click on the calculate it will show the days in the text field

check console it will show milli seconds and days.

Please let me know did it worked.

```js
function calculateDate(){
  var firstDate = document.getElementsByName("first")[0].value;
  var secondDate = document.getElementsByName("second")[0].value;
  var differenceInTime = Math.abs(new Date(secondDate).getTime() - new Date(firstDate).getTime());
  var differenceInDays = Math.ceil(differenceInTime / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
  console.log(differenceInTime + " milli seconds ", differenceInDays + " days")
  document.getElementById("output").value = differenceInDays
}
```

```html
<label for="first">From Date</label>
<input type="date" name="first" id="first">
<label for="second">To Date</label>
 <input type="date" name="second" id="second">
 <input type="button" onclick="calculateDate()" value="calculate">
 <input type="text" id="output">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But i dont want the difference between days.i want the differnce between tho shift timings.(duration of the shift) and i want it to calculate based on onchange event.if i change the value of second input box,then it should display the result

Comment: durarion of shift means .?? there will be two fields in and out isn't it

Comment: Yes.Shift Start time and Shift End time will be the two fields.I dont want to display the date here.I want to calculate the duration between two fields and i have to display it in a text box.

Comment: my code works well if i use the commented <p> tag instead of the input tag

Comment: i have added one more answer its working fine . Please check and let me know

Comment: i think i have updated the answer can you comment in that section.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$("#formShiftEndTime").on("change", function(){
  var startHour = $("#formShiftStartTime").val();
  var endHour =  $("#formShiftEndTime").val();
  calculate_time(startHour, endHour);
//   console.log(startHour);
})


function showTime(hours, minutes) {
    return ((hours < 10) ? '0' : '') + hours +
        ':' +
        ((minutes < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutes;
}

var startHour = $("#formShiftStartTime").val();
  var endHour =  $("#formShiftEndTime").val();
  
function calculate_time(formShiftStartTime, formShiftEndTime) {

    if( ($("#formShiftStartTime").val()) < ( $("#formShiftEndTime").val()))

    
{
    startTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + formShiftStartTime);
    endTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + formShiftEndTime);


    }
else{
    startTime = new Date('1-1-1 ' + formShiftStartTime);
    endTime = new Date('1-2-1 ' + formShiftEndTime);
}
    
    
   
    var difference = endTime - startTime;
    difference /= 1000 * 60; // convert to minutes
    var hours = Math.floor(difference / 60);
    var mins = Math.floor(difference % 60);
    
   document.getElementById('formDuration').value =    showTime(hours, mins);
   }
   </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Time difference</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="calculate" action=""> 
<div> 
    <p><label>Start Hour: <input type="time" name="formShiftStartTime" id="formShiftStartTime"/></label></p>
    <p><label>End Hour: <input type="time" name="formShiftEndTime" id="formShiftEndTime" /></label></p>
   
    <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Duration</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control " id="formDuration" name="formDuration" > 
                
            </div>

</div> 
</form>
</html>
```